# HTML Button does not call the onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, button, events

When I run this webpage I cannot get the Buttons to run the click event. I am creating the contents of the page via javascript in the window.onload function but the event handlers for the buttons are not working. I can't get the buttons to write to the console.

```js
var items = [
  "Item 1",
  "Item 2",
  "item 3",
  "item ......etc"
];

window.onload = function() {
  // Get container element to append the new element
  var container = document.getElementById("myContainer");
  // create an HTML element row for each item in the array
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.log(items[i]);
    let strItem = items[i];
    // Create a new div element
    let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.innerHTML = '<div class="row mx-auto py-1"> \
                              <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 px-5"> \
                                <label>' + (i + 1) + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + strItem + '</label> \
                              </div> \
                              <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 d-inline-block"> \
                                <button id="btn' + (i + 1) + '" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm d-sm-none">Button ' + (i + 1) + '</button> \
                                <button id="btn' + (i + 1) + '" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm d-none d-sm-inline-block">Button ' + (i + 1) + '</button> \
                              </div> \
                            </div>';

    // Append the new element
    container.appendChild(newDiv);

    // Get the button element
    let button = document.getElementById('btn' + (i + 1));

    // Add an event listener to the button
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      // Do something when the button is clicked
      console.log('Button ' + (i + 1) + ' was clicked');
    });
  }
};
```

```html
<section id="myContainer"></section>
```

Comment: I created a snippet from your code, seems like it's working for me. ID has to be unique, you have two buttons with same id. that's why only one button of yours is working. Use classes to bind event handlers to multiple elements.

Comment: window.onload = function is obsolete, use an event listener instead : 

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",readyEvent);

function readyEvent(e){
    //Your code here...
}

Comment: @cloned Thanks, you are right it was the two buttons having the same id was the problem. The button for the smaller screen size worked but I was testing it with the larger screen. My issue now is how can I get the event listener assigned to the other button without having to change the id. If I change the id then I have to create an event listener for that id too. idk if this is the correct way of going about this

Comment: @tatactic `onload` it is just not recommended to use it in modern programming as it overwrites other onload events. You use `addEventListener` to append the events. There are plenty of reasons why someone would still sue the onload event instead. While I agree that `addEventListener` in nearly all cases is the better method, I disagree with the statement that `onload` is obsolete.

Comment: @Shauny I think you overcomplicate the issue and programm way to inefficient for a for-loop. There is no reason to add the eventListener in the for-loop itself and program a static function to it. It would be easier to get all the elements with `querySelectorAll` and use `forEach`. Then add an Event Delegation to the function.

Answer (score 2):

The first issue is, that your buttons don't have a unique ID. That's why only the first button work.

Then you should move the `eventListener` out of the for loop and use `querySelectorAll` to select all your buttons. Then you use the `forEach` iteration to add the `eventListener` to all those buttons.

Last but not least use an Event Delegation (parameter inside the function of the `eventListener`). With that you can read out the id of the clicked button with: `parameter.target.id`.

```js
var items = [
  "Item 1",
  "Item 2",
  "item 3",
  "item 4"
];

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Get container element to append the new element
  const CONTAINER = document.getElementById('myContainer');
  // create an HTML element row for each item in the array
  for (let i = 1; i < items.length + 1; i++) {
    let strItem = items[i-1];
    // Create a new div element
    let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.innerHTML = `<div class="row mx-auto py-1">
                          <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 px-5">
                            <label>${i} &nbsp; &nbsp; ${strItem}</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 d-inline-block">
                            <button id="btn${i}-1" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm d-sm-none">Button ${i}-1</button>
                            <button id="btn${i}-2" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm d-none d-sm-inline-block">Button ${i}-2</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>`;

    // Append the new element
    CONTAINER.appendChild(newDiv);
  }
  
  //gets all the buttons
  const BUTTONS = document.querySelectorAll('button');
  //adds an EventListener to all the buttons
  BUTTONS.forEach(button =>
    button.addEventListener('click', function(element) {
      let buttonID = element.target.id;
      console.log(`Button ${buttonID} was clicked`);
    })
  )
});
```

```html
<section id="myContainer"></section>
```

I refactored your code to be cleaner and up to current standards.

Comment: Thanks tacoshy, great answer and I appreciate the effort. I had an idea that there must be a design pattern that I should be using such as the event delegation pattern but haven't reached that level yet.